# When I click the Appstore button in Passbook I receive the error: "Cannot connect to the iTunes store"

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, wallet

When I click on App Store, which rests below all of the features that Apple touts for the service, I am given an error where a prompt tells me that my phone can’t access the App Store. The error looks like this:

[image: image of error: "Cannot connect to the iTunes Store]

Is there a fix for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gotta Be Mobile](http://www.gottabemobile.com/) provides a great article detailing [the issue with Passbook and a fix](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2012/09/19/how-to-fix-passbook-error-in-ios-6/). I've reposted the fix from the article below:

> 1. First, head to the Settings in your iPhone.
> 2. Click on General.
> 3. Next, head to Date and Time which is down the list.
> 4. Once you’re in there, you’ll want to change Set Automatically to Off.
> 5. Go to Set Date & Time.
> 6. Click on Today’s Date. Once you do that, you’ll be given the option to change the date.
> 7. Move the year one year forward one year.
> 8. This will prevent the error from happening. If you wish to change the date back to the real date, simply set Set Automatically to On and
>      everything will return to normal.
> 9. Head into Passbook and click the App Store button

Something about moving the date up might be expiring a certificate or just the adjustment of time back to correct seems to make passbook behave better.